# Generating Isomorphic Graphs

Tags: graphs, graph-isomorphism

Is there a way of generating random isomorphic graphs for the purposes of testing tools like Nauty or BLISS? Every paper I've found says the authors had a database of certain isomorphic graphs, but I don't know how they constructed them or where I find test sets for graph isomorphism algorithms. I expect the answer to this question is no.

Is there a way to generate graphs that are *likely* to be isomorphic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. create a graph $G = (V, E)$ as you like
2. generate a random permutation $\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}(V)$, for example with [Knuth's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm)
3. create the graph $G' = (V, E')$ where $E' = \{(\sigma(u), \sigma(v))\mid (u, v)\in E\}$
4. Tada! $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic!

Comment: You can also use this approach to create a graph pair which is _almost_ isomorphic, by introducing small errors in the permutation.

Answer (score 4):

While Nathaniel's response answered my question perfectly, part of my question also asked about where to find testsets for graph isomorphism algorithms. As such, I thought I'd start a list.

- [http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/graphs.html)
- [Constructing Hard Examples for Graph Isomorphism](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.08154.pdf)